# PayPal Variables Add ref number

Tags: variables, paypal, addition

I'm struggling to add a variable to my PayPal payment form I need users to add a ref number so that I can identify the order so for example,

I normally use the email link option rather than the form option

- Add Ref No :
- Add Personal Message :

any help would so much appreciated

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HUMXQRA7T9Z3L">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a hosted button, so edit the button at [www.paypal.com/buttons](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=/buttons/) , view your saved buttons , find your button and edit it using the action menu.

In the Customize Button box, check the option to add a text field, and save your changes. This will generate new code to copy.

The hosted editor will only generate one text field, so if you need a button with more you'll need to create a new button with the first text field, and in step 2 uncheck the option to save the button at PayPal. When the code is created, click to remove the code protection. This will result in an unhosted button. Copy it to a text editor, and you can then extend the single text field to be two text fields, incrementing the ID number from e.g. 0 to 1 as is necessary for the second field.

You can read about [HTML variables for PayPal buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/).

Comment: yes i have but couldn't work out how to do it